# Cholesky decomposition issue when doing classification with a custom kernel in GPFlow

Tags: python, gpflow

I constructed a custom Matern32 kernel in GPFlow to operate on some expensively computed matrix values which contain the `distance' between my data points:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import gpflow

dat_mat = np.load('example_matrix.npy')

dat_diag = tf.constant(np.diag(dat_mat),dtype=tf.float64)
dat_mat = tf.constant(dat_mat,dtype=tf.float64)

def sub_mat(A,A2):
        global dat_mat
        A = tf.cast(A,tf.int32)
        A2 = tf.cast(A2,tf.int32)
        K_rows = tf.gather_nd(dat_mat, A)
        K_rows = tf.transpose(K_rows)
        K_mat = tf.gather_nd(K_rows, A2)
        K_mat = tf.transpose(K_mat)
        return tf.cast(K_mat, tf.float64)

class Matern32_RBF(gpflow.kernels.Kernel):
        global dat_mat, dat_diag
        def __init__(self):
                super().__init__(input_dim=1, active_dims=[0])
                self.var = gpflow.Param(1.0, transform=gpflow.transforms.Exp())
                self.mag = gpflow.Param(1.0, transform=gpflow.transforms.Exp())

        @gpflow.params_as_tensors
        def K(self, A, A2=None):
                if A2 is None:
                        A2=A
                K_mat = sub_mat(A,A2)
                z = np.sqrt(3)*K_mat*self.var
                return self.mag*(1+z)*tf.math.exp(-z)
        def Kdiag(self, A):
                A=tf.cast(A,tf.int32)
                K_diag = tf.cast(tf.gather_nd(dat_diag, A),tf.float64)
                z = np.sqrt(3)*K_diag*self.var
                return self.mag*(1+z)*tf.math.exp(-z)
```

This custom kernel was implemented for a binary classification task (example data files attached):

```py
Y=np.loadtxt('example_data.csv', usecols=1)
len_dataset = len(Y)

#These x-values only refer to the rows of my computed distance matrix 
X=np.array(range(len_dataset))
X=X.astype(int)

X=X.reshape(-1,1)
Y=Y.reshape(-1,1)

k = Matern32_RBF()

#Data_set split
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, random_state=1)

custom_config = gpflow.settings.get_settings()
custom_config.numerics.jitter_level = 1e-3

opt = gpflow.train.ScipyOptimizer()
model = gpflow.models.VGP(X_train, y_train, likelihood=gpflow.likelihoods.Bernoulli(), kern=k)

with gpflow.settings.temp_settings(custom_config):
        opt.minimize(model)
```

Running the above returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1334, in _do_call
return fn(*args)
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1319, in _run_fn
options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1407, in _call_tf_sessionrun
run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cholesky decomposition was not successful. The input might not be valid.
[[{{node VGP-cb46397c-6/Cholesky}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "trial.py", line 64, in
opt.minimize(model)
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpflow/training/scipy_optimizer.py", line 89, in minimize
**kwargs)
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpflow/training/external_optimizer.py", line 175, in minimize
optimizer_kwargs=self.optimizer_kwargs)
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpflow/training/external_optimizer.py", line 436, in _minimize
result = scipy.optimize.minimize(*minimize_args, **minimize_kwargs)
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 601, in minimize
callback=callback, **options)
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py", line 335, in _minimize_lbfgsb
f, g = func_and_grad(x)
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py", line 285, in func_and_grad
f = fun(x, args)
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 300, in function_wrapper
return function((wrapper_args + args))
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 63, in call
fg = self.fun(x, *args)
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpflow/training/external_optimizer.py", line 398, in loss_grad_func_wrapper
loss, gradient = loss_grad_func(x)
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpflow/training/external_optimizer.py", line 309, in eval_func
augmented_fetches, feed_dict=augmented_feed_dict)
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 929, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1152, in _run
feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1328, in _do_run
run_metadata)
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1348, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cholesky decomposition was not successful. The input might not be valid.
[[node VGP-cb46397c-6/Cholesky (defined at /home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpflow/models/vgp.py:108) ]]

Caused by op 'VGP-cb46397c-6/Cholesky', defined at:
File "trial.py", line 61, in
model = gpflow.models.VGP(X_train, y_train, likelihood=gpflow.likelihoods.Bernoulli(), kern=k)
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpflow/core/compilable.py", line 90, in init
self.build()
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpflow/core/node.py", line 156, in build
self._build()
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpflow/models/model.py", line 79, in _build
likelihood = self._build_likelihood()
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpflow/decors.py", line 67, in tensor_mode_wrapper
result = method(obj, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpflow/models/vgp.py", line 108, in _build_likelihood
L = tf.cholesky(K)
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_linalg_ops.py", line 767, in cholesky
"Cholesky", input=input, name=name)
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 788, in _apply_op_helper
op_def=op_def)
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3300, in create_op
op_def=op_def)
File "/home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1801, in init
self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cholesky decomposition was not successful. The input might not be valid.
[[node VGP-cb46397c-6/Cholesky (defined at /home/wjm41/.conda/envs/gpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpflow/models/vgp.py:108) ]]
```

I've tried varying the jitter level in the GPFlow settings as well as the initial values of the kernel parameters but that hasn't fixed this Cholesky decomposition issue. My custom kernel works fine for regression tasks so I'm not sure where the problem is. Is my data just really badly conditioned? (example data is a small subset of full dataset - see [here](https://www.filedropper.com/exampledata_1) for script and data.)

I'm using Python 3.6, GPFlow 1.3.0, and TensorFlow 1.13.1. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

I can not immediately see an issue with your code. My advice would be to debug the code to look at the K matrix you obtain just before the Cholesky failure.

Debugging in TensorFlow is cumbersome. I think the suggestion in [1] is quite good, of opening an IPython terminal inside an operation in the TensorFlow graph.

[1] https://wookayin.github.io/tensorflow-talk-debugging/#55  Slide 46 onwards.

Comment: Thank you for the debugging suggestion! I have done some poking around, and found that I just wasn't picking the right range of hyperparameters for the kernel to converge - with a much smaller value of self.var I no longer run into Cholesky decomposition issues.

However, the VGP model doesn't converge on sensible answers - all the entries in the kernel are the same, so all of the y predictions are the same regardless of x. Treating the task as simple GP regression between 0 and 1 does not have this problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Optimisation of variational GPs can be challenging sometimes. My general suggestion is to force to fit the data by first fixing the hyperparameters to sensible values and learning the variational parameters only. Then free up everything, and train.

Also, does the model fit with a normal Matern32 kernel, rather than your implementation?